# Problema leyendo datos c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy haciendo que el ususario ingrese un valor y el programa lo incremente en 10, pero no entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal porque no me guarda el valor incrementado:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
int valor = 0;
cout << "ingrese un valor: " << endl;
cin >> valor;

valor+10;

cout << "ahora el valor es " << valor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para incrementar una variable debes usar el operador `+=` de la forma:

```
valor += 10;
```

De esta forma, estarás incrementando y actualizando el valor de la variable.

¡Espero haber sido de ayuda! Un saludo.